# Compiling Scala before / alongside Java with Gradle

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors, gradle, cross-compiling

The default scala plugin task flow compiles Java before Scala so importing Scala sources within Java causes "error: cannot find symbol".
[image: scala task flow]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Java and Scala can be combined in the scala sources to have them compiled jointly, e.g.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/scala', 'src/main/java']
        }
        java {
            srcDirs = []
        }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep Java and Scala sources in separate directories and want all code to be joint compiled, this is the correct solution. An alternative is to keep the default setup and put the Java code to be joint compiled into `src/main/scala`, and the remaining Java code (if any) into `src/main/java`.

Comment: Thanks. We are wondering if the Java code compiled with compileScala will behave any differently than when compiled with compileJava. We assume they use the same compiler, thus produce the same bytecode underneath, but allow linking to scala source. Is that correct?

Comment: Joint compilation is controlled by the Scala compiler, which is responsible for invoking the Java compiler in this case. The result should generally be the same. Note that you'll have to configure `compileScala.options` rather than `compileJava.options` to affect Java compile options of joint-compiled Java code. (Scala compile options are controlled via `compileScala.scalaCompileOptions`.) You'll probably want to apply any such configuration to all compile tasks (e.g. `tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) { options ... }`).

Comment: I missed it at first when trying this technique: it's important to set the Java `srcDirs` to empty array if you're including `src/main/java` in the Scala `srcDirs`.

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle-talks/blob/master/talks/polyglot-gradle/src/slides/01-polyglot-gradle.md#scala-joint-compilation-2

Answer (score 4):

If your java code use some external libraries like Lombok, using scala compiler to build java class will failed, as scala compiler don't know annotations.

My solution is to change the task dependencies, make compiling Scala before Java.

```
tasks.compileJava.dependsOn compileScala
tasks.compileScala.dependsOn.remove("compileJava")
```

Now the task `compileScala` runs before `compileJava`, that's it.

If your java code depends on scala code, you need to do two more steps,

1. Separate the output folder of scala and java,

   ```
   sourceSets {
       main {
           scala {
               outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/scala/main")
           }
           java {
               outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/java/main")
           }
       }
   ```
2. Add the scala output as a dependency for `compileJava`,

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile files("$sourceSets.main.scala.outputDir")
   }
   ```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you :)

Comment: Won't work in Gradle 6 as task removal is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

for gradle kotlin dsl you can use this piece

```
 sourceSets {

    main {
        withConvention(ScalaSourceSet::class) {
            scala {
                setSrcDirs(listOf("src/main/scala", "src/main/java"))
            }
        }
        java {
            setSrcDirs(emptyList<String>())
        }
    }
    test {
        withConvention(ScalaSourceSet::class) {
            scala {
                setSrcDirs(listOf("src/test/scala", "src/test/java"))
            }
        }
        java {
            setSrcDirs(emptyList<String>())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this update from the future here, as it would saved me a day.

**gradle 6** doesn't support task dependencies modification, but here is what you can do:

```
// to compile Java after Scala
tasks.compileScala.classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
tasks.compileJava.classpath += files(sourceSets.main.scala.classesDirectory)
```

And here is [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sub:compile_deps_jvm_lang).