# How does one import a scala package in java?

Tags: java, scala, import

I have a gradle project; I have some scala classes in scala.com.EssencePVP.models that I want to import into my java code, which has the same package name for that matter.

The structure looks something like this:

src/main/java/com/EssencePVP/

src/main/scala/com/EssencePVP/models/

when I try to import my scala package (import com.EssencePVP.models.*) into java, I get this error message:

> EssencePVPMod/build/sources/java/com/EssencePVP/EssencePVP.java:56: error: package com.EssencePVP.models does not exist

clearly the problem is that is trying to look in the java directory, and not the scala directory. How do I fix this issue?

Thanks you.

Comment: Please note that imports have pretty much nothing to do with the actual directory where the source files are located - they are just a convenience so that you don't have to write the fully qualified name (package.name.ClassName) all the time. Your issue isn't with the import, but with adding the .class files compiled by scalac (from the Scala source files) in the classpath used by javac when compiling the Java files. How is your project built? For instance, do you use a build system like SBT or Maven?

Comment: (Forget the question about build systems - I should have read better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Gradle Scala plugin documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html), it seems that it only allows Java code  in `src/main/scala` to be compiled together with Scala code. You could try to set `srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/scala"]` for Scala plugin and correspondingly remove `src/main/java` from Java `srcDirs`.

Note that Maven and SBT don't have this limitation.

Comment: Thank you, I also referred to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261075/compiling-scala-before-alongside-java-with-gradle