# Gradle with truly mixed java and scala sources

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I created a sample project with a Java interface that is implemented by a Scala class and then a Java class with a main method that uses the Scala class. All Java sources at src/main/java and all Scala sources at src/main/scala

The code is simple and looks as follows (packages ommitted):

```
// java
public interface A {
    String getName();
}

// scala
class B(val name: String) extends A {
  override def getName: String = name
}

// java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B("aname");
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12'
}
```

Running 'gradle build' results in:

> /x/tmp/mixedJavaAndScala/src/main/java/Main.java:3: error: cannot find
>   symbol
>           B b = new B("aname");
>                     ^   symbol:   class B   location: class Main

Which means Gradle tries to compile firstly all Java and then all Scala sources.

Is there a way of compiling such a project?

Comment: The advice is stick to SBT. If you're keen on Gradle, just use https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/23261076/5722607 works?

Comment: Kudos Boris, it did work.