# How does one configure gradle (using kotlin dsl) to compile Scala before Java?

Tags: java, scala, gradle, kotlin

Context: porting the build script of legacy project from Ant to Gradle. The DSL of choice is Kotlin. A single directory contains both Scala and Java sources. The ant build executes `<scalac/>` before `<javac/>`. How can I pull the same off in Gradle?

There is an SO [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47176603/140185) that answers this question. However it doesn't serve my purpose for two reasons:

1. The reply assumes different source directories for Java, Scala sources. I'm obliged to work with a single directory that contains both.
2. Groovy DSL instead of Kotlin. Specifically how does one do the equivalent of `tasks.compileScala.dependsOn.remove("compileJava")` as mentioned there?

Here's my `sourceSets`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        val dirs = listOf("java/")
        java {
            setSrcDirs(dirs)
            outputDir = file("build-gradle")
        }

        resources {
            setSrcDirs(dirs)
        }

        withConvention(ScalaSourceSet::class) {
            scala {
                setSrcDirs(dirs)
            }
        }
    }
```